# Debugging with node-inspector: Cannot GET /

Tags: node.js, debugging, node-inspector

I am running a Nodejs server with an application which I want to debug. 
In order to achieve this using node-inspector I run the app as follows:

```
node-debug server.js
```

Unfortunately I can not access the webserver via URL anymore. Visiting http://127.0.0.1:8080 results in

```
Cannot GET /
```

However if I start the application the usual way with

```
node server.js
```

everything is fine (except for the fact that I can not debug). But I can access http://127.0.0.1:8080.

The '/' request is also not logged so it seems that it never reaches the server.

Hence the problem I have is: I can access the remote debugger via http://127.0.0.1:8080/debug?ws=127.0.0.1:8080&port=5858 but I can not start debugging because I can not trigger any action on the webserver via URL.

Oh and the debugger is not paused or anything. I skipped the first break point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved the problem by choosing a different port than 8080. It seems like the debugger uses this port. I was not aware of that because this port was familiar to me as I used it for my application.

Answer (score 0):

As [Schnodderbalken](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2102328/schnodderbalken) already answered, the problem lies in the application and inspector both using the same port 8080. If you tell inspector to use a different web port, 8082 for instance, the problem is solved.

You can do this by adding a parameter like so:
`node-inspector --web-port=8082`

You can then access inspector via http://127.0.0.1:8082/?port=5858

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! That's alright, you shouldn't post answers as comments. But you should instead explain your answer; why did you have to change the port? Quick googling requires a complete answer. Please [edit] your post.